# change date format from 12/12/12 to 2012-12-12 ios6

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have tried :

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
  NSDate *dateCheck = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12/12/12"];
  NSLog(@"Date = %@", dateCheck);
```

And the Output value is: `Date = 2012-12-11 18:30:00 +0000`

How Should I achieve the above result I don't know where the problem is.Please help.I would really appreciate the help.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
NSDate *dateCheck = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12/12/12"];
NSLog(@"Date = %@", dateCheck);

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateCheck];
NSLog(@"dateString = %@", dateString);
```

**Output:**

```
dateString = 2012-12-12
```

`@"MM/dd/yyyy"` represents 12/12/2012 and not 12/12/12. And If you want to convert to 2012-12-12, you need to set the date format as `@"yyyy-MM-dd"` and then convert to string again as shown above.

For more details on date format, check this [Unicode Date Format Patterns.](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Here the first conversion is changing string to date and then we are using `@"yyyy-MM-dd"` to convert to string again in required format.

Comment: @JacobWood, Is that the output of `NSLog(@"dateString = %@", dateString);`? Because I have run this code and I am getting proper output as in question.

Comment: Working Perfectly! Thanks ACB.

Comment: Addon question: Which chart lib is best for ios6 bargraph ? Thanks again just an addon question.

Comment: Thanks again ACB thats Awesome.Is there any step by step customization bar graph to your needs explained any where or any link like how to fill x-axis and y-axis and to take you to next screen after the tap on the bar graph of that year.Thanks again.+1 As I am a noob in charts/graphs and have no idea about anything .

Comment: @JacobWood, They have sample code available. You can download it and check it yourself. Shouldn't be tough. You can also check this tutorial [How To Draw Graphs with Core Plot,](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21656/discussion-between-jacob-wood-and-acb)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a date formatted in a specific way, you can keep using `NSDateFormatter`. Just add `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *string = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateCheck];
NSLog(@"Date = %@", string);`.
Also, as ACB noted, you need to convert from `@"12/12/2012"` if you want to use `MM-dd-yyyy`, otherwise you need to use `MM-dd-yy`

Comment: Thanks Echihl ACB has given the perfect Answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need two formatters. One to convert the original string to an `NSDate` (like you have now), and the second to convert the `NSDate` to a new string with the desired format.

Note that when you log as `NSDate`, it will always show in the format you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks rMaddy ACB has given the perfect Answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
`Date = 2012-12-11 18:30:00 +0000`
```

from

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
NSDate *dateCheck = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12/12/12"];
NSLog(@"Date = %@", dateCheck);

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateCheck];
NSLog(@"dateString = %@", dateString);
```

You are getting correct date. As the timestamp and locale are diffent, so you are not able to see 2012-12-12...

Comment: Thanks Anoop ACB has given the perfect Answer.